# Vue.js & Moment.js Output Date Rending Object Instead of Date String

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, vuejs2, vue-component

Not sure where I'm going wrong here, but I'm trying to output current date in a Vue.js component. But instead of returning a date string (i.e. 2017/02/02) it's returning a string of the object (??). Lost...

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" :value="initialDate">
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: ['date', 'user'],

        computed: {
            initialDate() {
                return this.date ? this.date : this.fetchCurrentDate
            }
        },

        methods: {
            fetchCurrentDate() {
                return window.moment()
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

In the browser, I'm seeing this as the input value:

```
function boundFn(a) { var l = arguments.length; return l ? l > 1 ? fn.apply(ctx, arguments) : fn.call(ctx, a) : fn.call(ctx) }
```

When it should be an actual date string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *call* the `fetchCurrentDate` function. Not reference it.

```
initialDate() {
      return this.date ? this.date : this.fetchCurrentDate()
}
```

Comment: God damn. FML...always the little things. Thanks for your help :) #TimeForBreak

Comment: @MikeBarwick Been there :)